# My sister and her husband with two children live in UK: how do I fill out the visa application?

Tags: visas, uk, applications

When I fill out the UK visa form, what should I indicate in the form for

> Do you have any family in the UK?

Yes or No?

Comment: Why would you doubt what the correct answer to this question is?

Answer (score 3):

Your sister is most definitely a family member.  You must answer "yes."